# Move a loop down a column

Tags: loops, do-loops

Is it possible to run a loop and then have it move down 1 column and run again?  Basically I liked the loop to run for the values in row 6 and once complete move down to row 7 and run again. I have tried to add a For loop into the macro but I can not get the corresponding rows to match up.

Comment: Hi ryan1. Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This kind of thing is possible in many applications and languages.  What environment are you looking to do this in?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what language do you want to do this in? Second of all, are you familiar with nested for loops? This is definitely the way to go.

Quick example in JavaScript:

```
// For each row iterate over its columns
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     var row = rows[i];
     for(var x = 0; x < row.columns.length; x++) {
         var column = row.columns[x];
     }
}
```